# WP8 - XAML Grid column expanding when text is too long

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a grid with column definitions.
Whenever the text inside a column cell exceeds the designated width, it shrinks the left hand column down.

Here's an example

[image: example of shrinking column cell]

And this is my xaml markup

```
<ItemsControl Name="rfbItems" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
            Style="{StaticResource contentItemsControl}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.7*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource App_Content_Grid}" TextAlignment="Left" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Description}" Style="{StaticResource App_Content_Grid_Subtle}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

How should I restrict this behavior without losing responsiveness in the layout?
Also, if there is a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do here (inside the datatemplate), please feel free to share :)

Comment: you've a bunch of grids created for each row, obviously they know nothing about each other and are quite easy to break. I'd say the easiest one is to use a DataGrid with custom cells, you can hide headers which'll make look the same as your current implementation.

Comment: Have you got any particular reason for ruling out the DataGrid?

Comment: You should indeed try and use a `DataGrid` for such stuff. say even something like `<DataGrid GridLinesVisibility="None" HeadersVisibility="None" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" />` would get you quite close to what you got without the problems you're having. Then it's just a matter of styling the control how you want.

Comment: It's quite stupid of me, but I forgot to mention it's a Windows Phone 8 app. There's not such thing as a datagrid in wp8 as far as I know. I'll look around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting margin and horizontal alignment to text boxes as below:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.7*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource App_Content_Grid}" TextAlignment="Left" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding Description}" Style="{StaticResource App_Content_Grid_Subtle}" />

</Grid>
```

Comment: Having individual grids at an item level is going to be fragile unless you set MinWidths for the columns.

Comment: I've read this on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc278072(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Bindingtocollections

Comment: Well, you're comment was most helpful and will work in most scenario's. I'll accept this one.

Answer (score 2):

The Grid doesn't have a limited width unless you give your StackPanel a fixed width. Setting Width="123" should work, HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" might do it as well (untested).

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for all your efforts, but I found a solution.
None of the answers worked for me, so feel free to find a fitting solution and I'll accept your answer.

```
<ItemsControl Name="rfbItems" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
            Style="{StaticResource contentItemsControl}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="125" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource App_Content_Grid}" TextAlignment="Left" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Description}" Style="{StaticResource App_Content_Grid_Subtle}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The first column has a fixed width, that's why the second column can't expand anymore.